# Condition always evaluates to true regardless of actual values

Tags: if-statement, delphi, boolean

I have created an `if` statement that I want to output a message using the `ShowMessage() function when an entered code matches a generated code. However, it still outputs the "well done!" message even when blatantly wrong.

Button code:

```pascal
procedure TfrmCAPTCHA.btnCheckClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sCode, sAnswer : string;
  bRightAnswer, bWrongAnswer : boolean;
begin

  {button to verify input}

  sANswer := Trim(edtAnswer.Text);
  sCode := edtCaptchaCode.Text;

  bRightAnswer := (sAnswer = sCode);
  bRightAnswer := True;

  bWrongAnswer := (sAnswer <> sCode);
  bWrongAnswer := False;

  if bRightAnswer then  
  begin
    btnCAPTCHAContinue.Show;
    Showmessage('Nicely Done, seems you''''re all set to go!' + #13 +
                'Press the continue button to collect your codes young wizzling');
  end
  else begin
    edtCAPTCHACode.clear;
    edtAnswer.clear;
    btnCAPTCHAContinue.Hide;
    Showmessage( 'That seems to be the wrong answer, please try again');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How about actually writing `if sAnswer = sCode then` - would that make more sense to you?

Comment: Your question boils down to: Why does this evaluate to true:`if true = true then Write('The answer is true); ?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you first set `bRightAnswer` to `true`/`false` depending on whether it's correct, but then you immediately overwrite it again with a fixed `true` regardless of the condition. Same thing in the next block setting `bWrongAnswer` to `false`:

```pascal
  bRightAnswer := (sAnswer = sCode); 
  bRightAnswer := True;     {regardless of what it was before, it's always true now}

  bWrongAnswer := (sAnswer <> sCode);
  bWrongAnswer := False;    {regardless of what it was before, it's always false now}
```

Remove those two lines.

You could further simplify the code by replacing `bWrongAnswer := (sAnswer <> sCode);` with `bWrongAnswer := not bRightAnswer;`, or going one step further and removing the `bWrongAnswer` variable entirely and just using `not bRightAnswer` everywhere in your code instead.

In fact, it seems that right now, you don't even use `bWrongAnswer` anyway, so there should be no damage in just removing it.

If you'd want to, you could also remove `bRightAnswer` and replace the `if bRightAnswer then` directly with `if sAnswer = sCode then`.

Comment: Note that you can remove "bWrongAnswer" altogether as it is equal to "not bRightAnswer".

Comment: Since `bWrongAnswer` is not used anywhere it can be disregarded anyway.